# A Relative time query which will work for both H2 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I need to write a filter condition in SQL something of this sort -

```
select * from table where date > now() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

(Works in MySQL)

But this query fails in H2( Spring Boot Application). Can someone help in formulating the query which will filter date from current time stamp to 2 days before.

Tried different queries - nothing seems to work with H2.

Comment: Can't you just do the date calculation in the Java code and simplify the query to `select * from table where date > ?`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DATEADD()`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) function in H2. Alternative to `NOW()` in H2 is [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp)

```
select * from table where date > DATEADD('DAY',-2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Comment: But DATEADD() doesn't work in MySQL. I want to have a function which works for both for mysql and H2

Comment: @user2885295 What if there is no such function ? Both are two different RDBMS.

Comment: I am hoping there will be some workaround for this problem as most of our dev DB is H2 and we have mysql as the Prod DB. Unless we have a common query which seamlessly works for both, we will experience unit test failures in the dev environment.

Comment: @user2885295 well having two different RDBMS for prod and dev in itself is a major blunder imho

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `DATEADD()` function

```
select * from table where date > DATEADD('DAY',-2, CURRENT_DATE)
```